# PyCharm's "Surround With" menu doesn't work on multiple lines

Tags: python, pycharm

I used PyCharm's "Surround With" menu to add an if statement around a line.

[image: Selecting one line and trying to surround with <code>if</code>]

However, if I try to surround multiple lines, I get a different menu.

[image: Selecting more than one line]

Why is this happening?  How do I use "Surround With" on multiple lines at once?

Comment: what ? Ive never heard of a multiline if condition?

Comment: @joran-beasley I have a lot of lines.I want to make pass them to if condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "make pass them to if condition"? Please give an example of the output you expect to see after doing this.

Comment: it works fine ... goto `code > surround with ... `  and select if ... it works fine for me with multilines

Comment: it sometimes works fine apparently .... I am able to get the same behaviour but I am not sure what triggers it or why

Comment: I had the same problem and noticed I wasn't selecting everything on the lines (which works fine for Tab or Shift+Tab - as long as you highlight part of a line it will be affected). When I carefully selected all code on the multiple lines, it worked. From OP's screenshot it looks like that wasn't an issue, but thought I'd mention in case anyone runs into the same issue and ends up here.

Answer (score 0):

I selected the multiple lines and I pressed tab to solve this problem.Thanks.